# Firebase Flashlight suddenly stops running on Compute Engine

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database, google-compute-engine, flashlight

I'm running Elastic Search on a Google Compute Engine instance. I've also set up [Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) to push all data inserted into Firebase directly into Elastic Search. Everything is working great and all is super fast. I can do queries by pushing a query node to Firebase, Flashlight will pick this up and returns all the items matching that criteria.

However, sometimes the machine just stops out of nowhere. I've done some research to see if:

- I can still access my VM by SSH - possible
- I can still curl my Elastic Search server - possible

When I'm searching in the logs I don't see any errors. As you can see it's all working as it should (2018-01-24 16:17:35.000) and 10 minutes later (2018-01-24 16:27:03.000) it's down and I can't do anything anymore. When setting up the Elastic Search server I pass the argument to log everything (error, info, warning, trace).

The strange thing is that sometimes it'll run for a couple of days and then suddenly stops.

Can you guys help me out where to search? Is there a possibility to somehow check the status of Flashlight and see if it's still running? Maybe restart when there is no response?

[image: logs]

**EDIT: Saw some error messages in the log, tried to increase memory but without any luck...**

[image: logs2]

Comment: I highly recommends to open an issue in the [Firebase issue tracker](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I'm not sure if Firebase is willing to help me with a problem that is being caused by Flashlight?